# On pop state not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images and when I click to a specific image the url changes to that id. But the problem is that `I can only go back once` (than the same url is repeated everytime I press the back button) and `forward button does not work` at all. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<img id="1" src="">
<img id="2" src="">
<img id="3" src="">
```

```
$('img').click( function() {
    update($(this).attr('id'));
});

function update(photo_id) {
    var state = { photo_id: photo_id},
    title = "",
    path  = "/mysite/" + photo_id;

    window.history.pushState(state, title, path);
}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var photo_id= document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

    update(photo_id);   
}
```

Comment: Do not store image url data into the history object of the window. It's not designed for that. It's not good practice to change the ui experience of the browser. A user expects his history buttons to work as designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling `update(photo_id)` on `onpopstate`? Your `update` function calls `window.history.pushstate`.

This means when you press the "Back" button, you're pushing that URL back to the history stack. That's why you get the same URL over and over again.

For example:

1. Visit your page `/mysite/`
2. Click Image 1, Change url to `/mysite/1`
3. Push state for Image 1
4. Click Image 2, Change url to `/mysite/2`
5. Push state for Image 2
6. Press Back, Change url to `/mysite/1`
7. **Push state for Image 1 occurs here**
8. Press Back, Urls stays at `/mysite/1`

Depending on what you intend to do, you can probably just remove `update(photo_id)` from `onpopstate`. I tested this out with the following fix and it worked. I was able to go back and forth properly on Chrome.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var photo_id= document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

    //Remove this line: update(photo_id);   
}
```

Comment: Thank You, It was such a stupid mistake Thanks a lot.